# How to recalculate texture_size in Kivy after condition reached

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to optimize the chat bubble mechanism, but still can't figure out the values that I need to set for my texture_size.

As you can see in the picture below, the first chat bubble seems to be okay, but when the **second** one **has more words** and **reach the width limit** then down the line, the label's **texture_size[0] will be replaced as its max-width** (*the orange one*) which means the box containing the label (*the green one*) that has its **size attach to the label's texture_size** will have **its width set to the max-width** and won't be able to track the label's texture_size anymore and cause some gaps as I showed below (*the red one*).

[image]

The gaps should be removed like this:

[image]

Here's a small app that I convert from the issue code.

**.py file**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ListProperty,BooleanProperty, StringProperty
from datetime import datetime

class HistoryBox(BoxLayout):
    chat_logs = ListProperty()
    def send(self, text):
        now = datetime.now()
        current_time = now.strftime("%H:%M")

        self.create_chatbubble(text,True,current_time)
        self.ids.field.text = ""
    
    def create_chatbubble(self,message,send_by_user,time):
        self.chat_logs.append(
            {
                "text":message,
                "send_by_user": send_by_user,
                "time": time,
            }
        )

class ChatBubble(BoxLayout):
    send_by_user = BooleanProperty()
    text = StringProperty()
    time = StringProperty()  

class App(App):
    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file("my.kv")

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    App().run()
```

**.kv file**

```
HistoryBox:

<HistoryBox>:
    orientation: "vertical"
    
    RecycleView:
        data: root.chat_logs
        viewclass: "ChatBubble"

        RecycleBoxLayout:
            id: box
            padding: dp(10)
            spacing: dp(15)
            orientation: "vertical"
            height: self.minimum_size[1]
            default_size_hint: 1, None
            default_size: None, None
        
    TextInput:
        id: field
        hint_text: "Write your message"
        multiline: False
        focus: True
        padding: dp(7)
        size_hint_y: .6
        size_hint_max_y: (len(self._lines)+1)*self.line_height
        on_text_validate:
            root.send(self.text)

<ChatBubble>:
    id: chtbld
    md_bg_color: [0, 0, 0, 0]
    size_hint_y: None
    height: wrapped.height
    pos_hint: {'right': 1} if chtbld.send_by_user == True else {'x': 0}
    #adaptive_height: True
    width: root.width
    padding: [10, 0, 10, 0]
    orientation: 'vertical'

    BoxLayout:
        id: wrapped
        height: msg_content.height + timed.height + 10
        width: msg_content.width + wid1.width + wid2.width
        size_hint: None, None
        pos_hint: {'right': 1} if chtbld.send_by_user == True else {'x': 0}

        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: 1,1,1,1
            RoundedRectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                radius: [10, 10, (1, -5), 10] if self.pos_hint == {'right': 1} else [10, 10, 10, (1, -5)]

        Spacer:
            id: wid1
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            height: msg_content.height + tc.height + wid3.height
            width: msg_content.width
            
            Label:
                id: msg_content
                text: root.text
                width: tc.width if self.texture_size[0] < tc.width else self.texture_size[0]
                height: self.texture_size[1]
                size_hint_y: None
                text_size: chtbld.width-dp(100) if self.width >= chtbld.width-dp(100) else None,None
                halign: 'left'
                color: 0, 0, 0, 1
                
            BoxLayout:
                id: tc
                size_hint: None, None
                height: timed.height
                width: timed.width + 3
                pos_hint: {'right': 1}
                spacing: 3
                Label:
                    id: timed
                    text: root.time
                    size_hint: None, None
                    size: self.texture_size
                    font_size: 9
                    bold: True
                    text_size: None,None
                    color: [.8, .8, .8, 1]
            Spacer:
                id: wid3
                height: 5
        Spacer:
            id: wid2

<Spacer@Widget>:
    id: wid
    width: 5
    size_hint: None, None
```

Just type anything like "welcomeeeeee toooooooooooooo" then minimize the window till the sentence down the line and you will notice the problem. Any help or advice would be helpful.

Comment: Your posted code doesn't seem to create the problem you mentioned.

Comment: @ApuCoder have you tried the example I mentioned at the end of the question?

Comment: Yes, but I found different issue like randomly changing chat bubbles' width etc.

Comment: @ApuCoder that's happened to me too, but still don't know why you didn't see the issue that I'm having. I have no clue how did that happen, looking for a way out :/

Comment: @ApuCoder when you minimize the window, stop right the moment a word is down the line and you will see the gaps.

Comment: Just based on a guess, try setting the value `size-hint` of the `Spacer` in each instance (like `size_hint_y: None` and `height: 5` etc.) instead of initializing with `(None, None)`.

Comment: @ApuCoder well that didn't do much, I just wonder if I can change this condition `text_size: chtbld.width-dp(100) if self.width >= chtbld.width-dp(100) else None,None` to something else, so it can recalculate the texture_size instead of setting it to a fixed-width after a word is down the line.